# How to get ID of each gmail message with Javascript from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, gmail

I wan't to create simple chrome extension for gmail and need unique id for each message.
In single mail id appears in URL (*https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/**15f38ed713048dc1***), but how to get id's for each email in gmail [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gd9q.png) and append them to row? like shown in attached immage [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMfoZ.png)?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing GMail while the user is on it is probably **not** what you want to do, because an end user, I wouldn't be okay with an application doing that in the background. In case the user **does know** that they're emails are being read, use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).